# I need to run a 12v fan (440w) from a 240v supply - what would be the best way?

Tags: power

I need to run a 12v fan (440w) from a 240v supply - what would be the best way? Should of mentioned that this fan is attached to a car conditioning rad and therefore dc. - Sorry.

Thanks to those who answered.

Comment: A 36.5 Amp fan? What are these, car radiator fans?

Comment: Please check your numbers to be sure the voltage, current and wattage you stated are correct.

Comment: A 750-1000W computer PSU *might* be able to provide that amount of current at 12V, and would probably be cheaper than any solution you build or buy elsewhere.

Comment: @jbarlow you should add that as an answer, and expand a bit on the 12V sourcing capability.

Answer (score 3):

At that power level, probably your best bet is to buy a suitable enclosed power supply such as the one pictured (600W) (despite the name 'enclosed' it will require an enclosure to cover the mains terminals etc.)

[image]

The exact minimum rating should be nailed down properly- the starting current will be higher than the run current, and most switching power supplies can behave undesirably when connected to such a load. It should not current limit when subjected to the motor stall current or you may have problems.

The rectifier/transformer that @Charles suggests would not have the startup problem (use a circuit breaker for protection), but it would be heavier. The regulated supply might be a bit easier on the commutator, assuming it's a brushed motor rather than a BLDC motor.

Answer (score 3):

For a $50 solution, consider using the +12V output on a computer power supply. If the fan does indeed need 440W, then it needs to provide at least 36.6A on the +12V rail – let's say it needs at least 45A to allow some margin. Most modern supplies will happily accept mains anywhere from 100-240V, 50-60 Hz.

In that case you could a part like the [EVGA 600B](http://www.evga.com/Products/Product.aspx?pn=100-B1-0600-KR), a 600W power supply that can source 49A on its 12V rail. This is just an example of a part that would work; other vendors might as well. You might even be able to salvage one from an older computer, but make sure to check the maximum current on the +12V rail – this is usually written on the label. Some PSUs have multiple +12V rails with limits on individual rails; you may to test if this is the case, and possibly use [a load sharing circuit](http://www.edn.com/design/power-management/4419835/Multiple-PSUs-share-load) or better, find one that is above the limits.

As discussed in [guides like this one](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/blog/convert-atx-psu-to-bench-supply.html), you will need to provide a dummy load on the +5V to stabilize the power supply's feedback loop, and a momentary contact mechanical switch to turn the power supply on. Exactly what dummy connections and the pinouts will depend on the class of supply you use; that guide is for ATX supplies.

Of course, the power supply will contain its own fan, which may not be suitable depending what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Note, some supplies have multiple 12V rails with lower individual capacities. And make sure your wiring can support the voltage and current.

Comment: A computer PSU is likely to go into shutdown as soon as such a motor is connected.

Comment: @Jasen why is that?

Comment: Stall current. typically about 10 times run current. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inrush_current#Motors

Answer (score 0):

A transformer and rectifier would be sufficient. The rectifier would need to be able to withstand a substantial but brief high inrush current that will occur when the motor is started. The impedance of the transformer will limit the inrush current. You shouldn't need any voltage regulation or filtering for the power supply.

For a complete purchased supply, look at automotive battery chargers.

Added re comments:

A battery charger that is rated to supply the required current should come with adequate cables. The wire size required is dependent on the type of insulation, the temperature of the environment, bundled or open-space wiring, and whether the wire is copper or aluminum. For a long wire run, voltage drop needs to be considered. Look for tables online or in electrical codes.

I have assumed that this is a commutator DC motor since a brushless motor requires a controller rather than a power supply and 440 W seems too large to have a built-in electronic commutator.

A battery charger with a built-in electronic charge control would probably not work very well. You need a simple one that is just a rectifier and transformer or perhaps an electronic voltage converter.

Comment: This was my preferred option but would the cabling withstand the 32 amps?

Answer (score 0):

step down transformer and rectifier is enough to run the fan.
Transformer will step down the voltage form 240v/12v and 
Rectifier will convert the AC to DC.

Comment: It depends. A brushless fan will maybe unhappy about the ripple of 100%.

Answer (score -1):

A lighter, smaller solution would be to rectify it, then use a buck converter.  But it's going to be a big buck converter, and may not be any smaller than the suggested transformer.

Comment: "_A lighter, smaller solution ..._" Lighter and smaller than what? (Answer order changes depending on votes and user's sort order.) Then you say "_... and may not be any smaller ..._" Well which is it?

Comment: rectify and PWM would be smaller still, if the motor can handle the voltage,  and you have the same electrical isolation issues.